# How to create pop up div in MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I read several topics here and tried to create pop up window but it's not working and I can't find the reason why?

I have a div call:

```
<input class="k-button" style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00;" type="button" value="Filter" onclick="OpenPanel()" />
```

I have second div:

```
    <div id="filterPanel" title="Filter Options">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Vehicle", "Home", new { id = "Id" }))
        {       
        <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Search Criteria:</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="k-in" style="width: 100px; padding: 0; font-size: 0.9em;" type="text" id="model" name="model" value="@Model.Filter.Model"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>
                            @{
                var statusItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value="None",
                        Text="None",
                        Selected= Model.Filter.Status == "None" ? true : false
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value="New",
                        Text="New",
                        Selected= Model.Filter.Status == "New" ? true : false
                    }
                };
            }
            @Html.DropDownList("Status", statusItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "k-dropdown", @style= "width: 120px;font-size: 0.9em; padding: 0;"})

                        </td>
                    </tr>                      
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="k-button" style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter" /></td>
                        <td><input class="k-button" style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter" value="Remove Filter" onclick="ClearFilter()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        }
            </div>
```

I have second jQuery/java script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filterPanel').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });

    function OpenPanel() {
        $('#filterPanel').dialog("open");
    }

});
```

In controller everything also seems fine:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Vehicle(FormCollection collection)
{
   ...
   return View(vehicle);
}
```

Div always are showing on page, and no pop up message on button click (script are not called I guess).
I'm definitely are missing something but I can't see it. Where is the problem?

P.S Also, for some reason functions in my jQuery became "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

**Edit:**
I have included jquery.ui

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

Comment: include jquery ui files...

Comment: They are included. Wait a sec, I will update question

Comment: which jqueryui version you r using??

Comment: jquert-ui-1.8.24 and jquery-1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Add below [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/9zTGL/) in your page and make sure it works. If not then update jquery libraries versions.

```
<div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#open').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
                    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And if it works then change the existing caller button what you are already using.

```
<input id="open" class="k-button" type="button" value="Filter" onclick="OpenPanel()" />
```

Comment: Tried this. Not working. On both functions: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Can't get it, is this really library issue? Because I tried to make similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RokXgBFSvp8&feature=youtu.be and there was used exactly 1.8.24 and 1.82 jquert versions.

Comment: did you see fiddle example? The code is absolutely working code. Have you tried updating jquery and UI libraries?

Comment: Updated. Will see soon enough (build)

Comment: Nope. Library update didn't done a thing. And for some reason $("#dialog").dialog({ is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog() is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. It's clear that jquery UI library has not loaded in the page. Add this line of code in your page <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yea, I figured it out, but I used @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui"). Anyway, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for the popup. Let's have a small setup here.

We would have a view model for the main form:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string ValueId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            };
        } 
    }

    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

and a view (~/Views/Home/Index.aspx):

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ValueId, Model.Values) %>
        <br/>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.NewValue) %>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Suggest Value", "New", "NewValue", null, new { id = "new-value-link" }) %>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    <% } %>

    <div id="dialog"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

then we could take care for the popup. We define a view model for it:

```
public class NewValueViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class NewValueController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult New()
    {
        return PartialView(new NewValueViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(NewValueViewModel model)
    {
        var newValue = string.Format("{0} - {1}", model.Foo, model.Bar);
        return Json(new { newValue = newValue });
    }
}
```

and a corresponding partial view (~/Views/NewValue/New.ascx):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.NewValueViewModel>" 
%>

<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "new-value-form" })) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo) %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar) %>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
<% } %>
```

Now all that's left is to write a bit of javascript to wire everything up. We include jquery and jquery ui:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and a custom javascript file that will contain our code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#new-value-link').click(function () {
        var href = this.href;
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load(href, function (result) {
                    $('#new-value-form').submit(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (json) {
                                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                                $('#NewValue').val(json.newValue);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```